# Why is react-bootstrap components not working

Tags: reactjs, react-hooks, react-bootstrap

I have tried react-bootstrap components but it is not working. I have installed it perfectly but I do not know where is the problem.

App.js

```
import './bootstrap.min.css';

import Button from 'react-bootstrap/Button';



 function App() {

  return (
    <Button>
  Hello 
    </Button>
    
  );
}

export default App;
```

Error On the Browser

[image]

I tried many solutions but none is working.

Comment: Where did you render it?

Answer (score 2):

It's working. Maybe you are importing the file `import './bootstrap.min.css';` wrong. Can you confirm?

I tried with this code:

```
import 'bootstrap/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css';
import './App.css';

import Button from 'react-bootstrap/Button';

function App() {
  return <Button>Hello</Button>;
}

export default App;
```

Output:

[image]

Answer (score 0):

- make sure that you are install bootstrap library in project folder not out side it
- cd (your project name)
- and install it
- Happy coding

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).